# How to get the globally unique identifier of a Shopify store using GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, remix.run

I am trying to get the `shopID` using a GraphQL. I can get the value using a GraphQL app but when I run the query through a function I get null.

```js
export async function getShopId(admin) {
  // Your GraphQL query to get the shop ID
  const GET_SHOP_ID = `
    {
      shop {
        id
      }
    }
  `;

  try {
    // Execute the GraphQL query using the admin object
    const { data, errors } = await admin(GET_SHOP_ID);

    if (errors) {
      // Handle errors if the query fails
      console.error('Error fetching shop ID:', errors);
      return null;
    }

    // Access the shop ID from the query response
    const shopId = data?.shop?.id;
    console.log(data);

    if (!shopId) {
      // Handle the case where shop ID is not available
      console.error('Shop ID not found in the GraphQL response.');
      return null;
    }

    return shopId;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in getShopId:', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

I am calling this function through a loader so the `admin` and the `graphql` should exist but I keep getting null. Here is the loader

```js
export async function loader({ request, params }) {
  const { admin, session } = await authenticate.admin(request);
  const { shop } = session;
  const graphql = admin.graphql;

  // Example: Fetching shop ID using getShopId
  const shopIdm = await getShopId(graphql);
  console.log("shopId-->" + shopIdm);
  return null
}
```